# Remove Un-selected cells from Collection View

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need some help with a problem. I have a collection view that was loaded with data from firebase. The user is able to multi-select them, and after the selection I wanted to remove the un-selected cells from the collection view.
I am stuck on this, can anybody help?
I've managed to perform the opposite. I can remove the Selected cells. But somehow I am having issues to do the opposite.
Below you have the code for the selected cells. I need the unselected.

```
  if let selectedCells = dogsCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
        // 1
        let items = selectedCells.map { $0.item }.sorted().reversed()
        // 2
        for item in items {
            dogsArray.remove(at: item)
        }
        // 3
        dogsCollectionView.deleteItems(at: selectedCells)
    }
```

Comment: Looks like there is no need for you to `sorted()` and `reversed()` for the items array. I would recommend you to add the selected state property to your `item` data structure. If you would not like to keep that state in your model, you can just iterate all of the objects in your array and ask the collection for the `indexPathsForSelectedItems`, then every time you iterate an object that is part of selected index paths you add this to a your new collection. While doing that you should record the index paths for the items that were not selected then call `deleteItems(at:`.

Comment: I'll try, update it soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1. Get the array of the `IndexPath`s of the selected cells. Convert to a set.
2. Query the data source for the sections.
3. Loop through the sections and ask for the number of items.
4. Build a set of `IndexPath`s of all rows in all sections. (A set of all
   `IndexPath`s)
5. Remove the set of selected cells from the set of all cells. That is
   your set of not selected cells.

Now use your code above to remove the set of not selected cells.

### EDIT

Note that making both arrays into sets makes this MUCH faster. If you loop through the array of cell `IndexPath`s and do a `contains` on each item in the array of selected items you'll get `O(n²)` performance, which does not scale well at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did help a lot

Comment: If this answer solves your problem you should accept it.

Comment: ...And once you have enough reputation, it's considered good form to up-vote answers that you consider helpful (Both answers to your questions and to other questions.) Up-voting is optional, whereas accepting the first/best answer to your question is a very strong norm.